# replace a string with a regex in multiple files

Tags: regex, powershell, notepad++

I have more than 10000 text files that I want to replace the string `searchResult` with a regex in that specific text file using Notepad++ or PowerShell. For example here is one of the text files:

```
searchresult : [{"name": myRegexMatch .....}
```

After substitution:

```
myRegexMatch : [{"name": myRegexMatch .....}
```

The regex match is different in every file. I just want to replace `searchResult` in every single file with the regex in that file.

Comment: First off, please see [Help Center - Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). There are a ton of resources there on [how to properly ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including [editing help (formatting)](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and what you should include in your question to make it a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I can foresee many issues with what you've given us as an example and what potential answers you may receive. Ever tried to match a regex pattern with regex? It's not easy.

Comment: Your question could be much clearer if you were to provide a more detailed example with real values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should kind of get you started

```
$regex = '(?<=searchresult\s:\s\[{"name":\s).*(?=})'
Get-ChildItem $pathToFiles -Recurse  | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
ForEach-Object {
    $text = (Get-Content $_ -Raw)
    $value = [regex]::Match($text, $regex).Groups[1].Value
    $text -replace "searchresult",$value | Set-Content -path $_
}
```

Comment: Hi. there is just one searchResult in each file

Comment: @johnsadeghi Are you just looking for the regex to match that scenario? Or do you need the powershell method of how to do it?

Comment: I can do simple find and replace string with regex manually in every file. but there is more than 10000 files and I am looking for powershell method to do it it once.

Comment: thank you for your help. the code just removes the searchResult in all files. but as you said its where i can to start working on the code. thanks for your help again.

Comment: You might need to tweak the regex expression.  A good source is regexr.com
Please don't forget to mark  this as the answer and upvote if it helped you out

Comment: @johnsadeghi If you need help with the regex let me know.  I am happy to help

Comment: @johnsadeghi Make sure to upvote and mark this as the answer so that other people can be helped by it as well

Comment: If your text documents are large I would be careful with reading and storing the entire document in memory. If this is the case you can always go for an iterative approach across the pipeline `Get-Content $_ -Raw | % { #perform replace | Set-Content -Path $_ -Append }` or using the underlying .Net File\Streaming classes or at the very least reading the data in chucks, to perform this type of operation in a memory performant way.